# S/W Upgrade mode problem

Tags: updates

I have a LG P999 and I want to flash the baseband however when I go into S/W upgrade mode (Volume down + power button; without battery) my PC does not recognize the phone :(. When its connected and on fully the computer sees it, but not when I hold the volume down button and plug it in. Is there any solution to this? I have also tried holding both volume buttons down installing the APX drivers but that did not work. I have all the drivers for the phone.

Thanks

Comment: Why do you connect your LG P999 *without* battery to computer? AFAIK, there is a special state of the phone exclusively for service personnel. I observed this when they did so and got this explanation. There could be a special USB driver part of LG's B2B application that would enable them to configure/read info about the phone. For end users like us, fastboot, recovery, adb are the three states for which LG has released drivers. For your requirement, try what you did with battery in the phone.

Comment: Also, I have heard and used `Home` + `Volume down` + `Power` combination and not `Volume down` + `Power` combination.

Answer (score 0):

Are you talking about download mode? AFAIK you have to press and hold menu key while connecting your phone to your computer via USB. Volume keys are used to boot in recovery mode. I have not tried it on the phone you mentioned though.

Answer (score 0):

If your computer didn't recognize your phone while in recoverymod, may be because you **didn't enabled USB Debugging in phone settings**  (***settings-->applications-->development*** )
Enable it and try again.

Comment: It is enabled but its still not showing up in the device manager. It only shows up if I connect the phone when fully on